# reactjs props handler wont get reached

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a handler meant to save data and call to another handler in the post. Thing is, it won't reach the props handler. I am passing it in the child component, but when accessing the handler from it, it will not reach back (this.props.onSave()). Any ideas ?

```html
const {onSave} = this.props

handleSaveOrderClick = () => {
        axios.post('/api/products/save', this.state.purchase).then(response => {
           this.props.onSave()
        })
    }
 
//parent

    handleSaveOrder = () => {
        this.setState({
            productDialogOpen: false,
            selected: [],
        })

    }
      <OrderDialog
            onSave={this.handleSaveOrder}
        />
```

Edit: if i console.log(onSave) inside the child component, it will print the handler.

Comment: please provide your involved component implementation

Comment: added it now :)

Comment: are you sure you're getting success response for the api call if not try adding `catch`.

Comment: Where do you call `handleSaveOrderClick ` ?

Comment: @AtishayJain you had the right answer :D it was an api error